# how to add buttons Dynamically in List Activity in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

friends,

i want to put description and buttons dynamically can any one guide how can i do that??

i have data in the form of object list/array i.e ID,Title
and want to display in list activity like..

TITLE  [Details Button]  [Edit Button] (repeating in list activity)

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595429/android-listview-with-complex-data-model).

Comment: the example you have given leads to page not found. could you please give me exact url.. list14 example page does not found.. :(