# How do i add buttons dynamically using array adapter from class that extends list activity?

Tags: android

Below is my code

```
    public class TicketAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ticket> {
        Context context;
        int layout;

        public TicketAdapter(Context context, int layoutFile, List<Ticket> tickets) {
            super(context, layoutFile, tickets);

            this.context = context;
            this.layout = layoutFile;

        }

        // overide a method which will be called for every ticket in ticket list

        public View getView(int position, View finalView, ViewGroup parent){
            Ticket ticket = getItem(position);
            ticketDataHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            // 0th index - final view will not be ready
            if(finalView == null){

                holder = new ticketDataHolder();
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                finalView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket, null );
                holder.ticketName = (TextView)finalView.findViewById(R.id.btnticketType);
                finalView.setTag(holder);
                Log.d("Helllloooo", finalView.getTag()+"");
            }else{
               holder = (ticketDataHolder) finalView.getTag();
            }

            holder.ticketName.setText(ticket.getTicketType());

            return finalView;
        }

        class ticketDataHolder{
            TextView ticketName;
            HorizontalScrollView ticketView;

        }
    }
```

## Below is my list activity class

```
    public class TicketActivity extends ListActivity {

        TicketAdapter ticketAdapter;
        String[] ticketNames ={"Adult", "Weekly","Mothly", "Yearly"};
        List<Ticket> ticketList;

        public void onCreate(Bundle data){
            super.onCreate(data);
            ticketList = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
            for (int i = 0; i< ticketNames.length; i++) {
                Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
                ticket.setTicketType(ticketNames[i]);
                ticketList.add(ticket);
            }
            ticketAdapter = new TicketAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.ticket, ticketList);
            setListAdapter(ticketAdapter);
        }
    }
```

My  XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/table_view"
android:layout_width="200sp"
android:layout_height="300sp">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnticketType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:text="Buttons Buttons Buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnticketType1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:text="Weekly PrePaid" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## My button xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval"  >
            <corners android:radius="1dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval"  >
            <corners android:radius="1dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <solid android:color="#58857e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval"  >
            <corners android:radius="1dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

---

I am trying to populate buttons dynamically using arrayAdapter. Everything is working fine except buttons are not appearing in horizontal scroll view.  I am using andriod api level 21.

My problem is buttons are not appearing horizontally.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Ravan

Comment: Where is your activity_layout? Where are you setting Adapter with your Container?? When you use my_button.xml
.......
Caution - Container layout inside Scrollview May be cause touce issue..

Comment: You need a custom adapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595429/android-listview-with-complex-data-model][1]